# iOS 6 presentviewcontroller displays blackscreen

Tags: xcode, view, ios6

I just built a little App to test the use of changing views programmatically, so I have my two views in the storyboard and my two classes.
Now I want that when I tap the button in my ViewController that it shows up the RedViewController. But when I tap on this button, I just can a black screen.
Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

```
-(IBAction)showred:(id)sender{

    RedViewController *viewController = [[RedViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks Michael

Comment: Check your RedViewController, maybe you missed xib or didn't load controls

Comment: I have the RedViewController interface in my storyboard and it is linked to the RedViewController, so this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the storyboard and have defined your `RedViewController viewcontroller`'s view there, you do not write any code to switch to this view, nor do you have to hook up your button to an `IBAction`. Instead you had to drag from the button that should initiate the transition to the RedViewController's view in the storyboard.
In your code, you create an new `RedViewController` object with an `init`, i.e. without any informastion how its view should like - thus its black.